# Memory error while using memcpy?

Tags: c++, dcmtk

I'm using dcmtk library to modify the pixel data of a multi frame compressed dicom image. So, to do that, at one stage in an `for` loop I take the pixel data of each decompressed frame and modify them according my wish and try to concatenate each modify pixel data in a big memory buffer frame by frame. This core process of `for` loop is as below.

The problem is after the first iteration it gives memory at the line of the code where I call the function `getUncompressedFrame`. I think it's happening because of the line `memcpy(fullBuffer+(i*sizeF),newBuffer,sizeF);`, as when I remove that line there's no error at that time and the whole for loop works absolutely fine.

Could you please say me if I'm making a mistake in working with memcpy? Thanks.

```
Uint32 sizeF=828072;// I just wrote it to show what is the data type. 
Uint8 * fullBuffer = new Uint8(int(sizeF*numOfFrames));//The big memory buffer
for(int i=0;i<numOfFrames;i++)
{
    Uint8 * buffer = new Uint8[int(sizeF)];//Buffer for each frame
    Uint8 * newBuffer = new Uint8[int(sizeF)];//Buffer in which the modified frame data is stored 
    DcmFileCache * cache=NULL;
    OFCondition cond=element->getUncompressedFrame(dataset,i,startFragment,buffer,sizeF,decompressedColorModel,cache);
    //I get the uncompressed individual frame pixel data 
    if(buffer != NULL)
    {
        for(unsigned long y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            for(unsigned long x = 0; x < cols; x++)
            {
                if(planarConfiguration==0)
                {
                    if(x>xmin && x<xmax && y>ymin && y<ymax)
                    {
                        index=(x + y +  y*(cols-1))*samplePerPixel;
                        if(index<sizeF-2)
                        {
                            newBuffer[index]  = 0;
                            newBuffer[index + 1]  = 0;
                            newBuffer[index +2]  = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        index=(x + y +  y*(cols-1))*samplePerPixel;
                        if(index<sizeF-2)
                        {
                            newBuffer[index]  = buffer[index];
                            newBuffer[index + 1]  = buffer[index + 1];
                            newBuffer[index + 2]  = buffer[index + 2];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        memcpy(fullBuffer+(i*sizeF),newBuffer,sizeF);
        //concatenate the modified frame by frame pixel data
    }
```

Comment: Run in a debugger, if it stops there then examine the values of `i` and `sizeF` to see if they look okay. If it doesn't stop, then set a breakpoint.

Comment: I have run the debugger, i and sizeF gives the appropriate number. The program works fine I don't use the line of code with memcpy, but if I use it, the program breaks.

Comment: what's the purpose of that whole nested x y loop? and BTW, instead of 'index=(x + y +  y*(cols-1))*samplePerPixel;' you could do  why do you use 'index=(x + y*(cols))*samplePerPixel;', right?

Comment: Uint32 sizeF=0;???????? you are allocating 0 size?

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to show the data type of the `sizeF`, I do get the value of the sizeF from another method, it returns something like 828072. :)

Comment: Please do not "fix" the error in the question. That makes it impossible to compare your original code to the suggestion(s) in the answer(s).

Comment: Okay, thanks for reminding it :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the declaration of `fullBuffer` to this:

```
Uint8 * fullBuffer = new Uint8[int(sizeF*numOfFrames)];
```

Your code didn't allocate an array, it allocated a single `Uint8` with the value `int(sizeF*numOfFrames)`.

Comment: Yes, that was big big mistake, Ah! my bad. Thanks! I will try now. I guess my I eyes deceived me.

Answer (score 3):

```
Uint8 * fullBuffer = new Uint8(int(sizeF*numOfFrames));
```

This allocates a single byte, giving it an initial value of `sizeF*numOfFrames` (after truncating it first to `int` and then to `Uint8`). You want an array, and you don't want to truncate the size to `int`:

```
Uint8 * fullBuffer = new Uint8[sizeF*numOfFrames];
                              ^                 ^
```

or, to fix the likely memory leaks in your code:

```
std::vector<Uint8> fullBuffer(sizeF*numOfFrames);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the method *getUncompressedFrame* is doing an inner memcpy to cache, then it makes sense why, as you are passing a null pointer as argument for the cache, with no memory allocated.